# SQL Server before trigger

Tags: sql-server, triggers

I need to control table values uniqueness. It cannot be done by an index or a constraint (error message must show data from another table). I thought of  after trigger but since it fires after the insert the below trigger will fire even if values are unique.

```
--table
CREATE TABLE Names (Id IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL, Name VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL) 

--first record 
INSERT INTO Names VALUES ('John') 

--trigger 
CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[Names_Insert_Trigger]
ON [dbo].[Names]
FOR INSERT, UPDATE
AS
    SET NOCOUNT ON

    IF EXISTS (SELECT Name 
               FROM inserted 
               WHERE EXISTS (SELECT * FROM Names N JOIN inserted ON N.Name=inserted.Name))
    BEGIN
       RAISERROR('This name is already registered in file XYZ.', 16, 1)
       ROLLBACK TRAN

       SET NOCOUNT OFF
       RETURN
    END

    SET NOCOUNT OFF

    --I add another record with different value and the trigger fires 
    INSERT INTO Names VALUES ('Steven')
```

I also thought of an `instead of insert` trigger but the actual table has identity set and will likely get new columns in the future which would require updating the trigger code at each change so I can't use the below code:

```
CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[Names_Insert_Trigger]
ON [dbo].[Names]
INSTEAD OF INSERT
AS
   SET NOCOUNT ON

   IF EXISTS (SELECT Name 
              FROM inserted 
              WHERE EXISTS (SELECT * FROM Names N JOIN inserted ON N.Name=inserted.Name))
   BEGIN
       RAISERROR('This name is already registed in file XYZ.', 16, 1)
       ROLLBACK TRAN

       SET NOCOUNT OFF
       RETURN
   END
   ELSE
       INSERT INTO Names 
          SELECT * FROM inserted

       SET NOCOUNT OFF
```

Any ideas how to solve it?

Regards,
Przemek

Comment: Why not use a UNIQUE constraint?

Comment: *"error message must show data from another table"* Why not handle that client-side after the normal `UNIQUE` violation is reported?

Comment: There is no trigger of Before type, but we do have After triggers and instead of triggers.

Comment: As a sidenote, `BEFORE` triggers have been requested to Microsoft long before, but they have systematically ignored those request: https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/361223/add-before-triggers-not-the-least-for-ddl-statements

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use an after trigger.  Just use `COUNT` instead of `EXISTS`.  You should still have a non-unique index on name to optimize performance and concurrency.

```
IF (SELECT COUNT(*)
    FROM inserted AS i
    JOIN dbo.Names AS N ON 
        N.Name = i.Name
    GROUP BY N.Name
    ) > 1
BEGIN
    RAISERROR...
END;
```

Answer (score 0):

The real solution is to use the `UNIQUE` constraint to this problem, it's designed to solve it and it's much more performant and safer than a trigger for this usage. The error message is better built client-side and ignore the server genereated one, save for determining the exact reason.

But if you really want to follow the trigger route, use the `AFTER` version, but fix the query for detect duplicates:

```
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT Name
    FROM Names
    WHERE id NOT IN (SELECT id FROM inserted)
) PreviousNames
INNER JOIN inserted ON PreviousNames.Name = inserted.Name
```

(I'm just showing the query to check duplication that goes into the `IF EXIST` instruction, not the whole trigger).
It begins by creating a subquery that gets the names NOT being inserted (so that you don't get a false positive), then simply joins again to inserted to check if any value is in both tables.

There is an additional problem that can happen when using `SNAPSHOT` issolation level. In this mode, the trigger will **NOT** see the changes made by other connections, nor they'll be blocked until the trigger ends. I'm not quite familiar with the details, but will leave this article as reference and possible solutions: https://sqlserverfast.com/?s=snapshot+integrity